# how to use map() in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that captures images from the camera and gallery that is working but is returning an array. I need to make a map() that just returns an image.

This is my function:

```
const [uriImg, setUriImg] = useState('');

function imagePickerCallback(data) {

if (data.didCancel) {
    console.log(`cancelado ${data}`)
    return;
  }

  if (data.error) {
    console.log(`Ocorreu um erro ${data}`)
    return;
  }

  if (!data.uri) {
    console.log(`Diferente de uri ${data}`)
    return;
  }
  setUriImg(data);
  console.log(`Setando ${data}`)
  
}
```

This is where I call the function

```
<Image 
    source = {{
    uri: uriImg
    ? uriImg.uri
    : 'https://socialistmodernism.com/wpcontent/uploads/2017/07/placeholder-image.png?w=640'}}
    style={styles.placeholderImage}
 />

      <View style={styles.optionsCamera}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchCamera({},imagePickerCallback)
          }>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Abrir câmera</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({},imagePickerCallback)
          }>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Escolher imagem</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

how to use map() to return only one image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions must be in English on StackOverflow. See [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) Please either update your question to be in English (and let the community help you with grammar and spelling through edits), or post on a language specific StackExchange site (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I imagine you'd want `setUriImg(data.uri)` instead of `setUriImg(data)`?

Comment: I tried using setUriImg(data.uri) but it still has the same problem, it's returning an object instead of returning a single image. I need to use map() to handle the error, but I don't know how to use it.